# I cannot adjust brightness in Lenovo G580 laptop windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, brightness

I am not able to adjust the brightness on my Lenovo G580 laptop. There is also no notification when clicking on the volume icon.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What is the problem? Can you not *click* on the icons, or can you click on them but not adjust anything? Or do the sliders move; your screen just doesn't adapt?

Comment: Don't forget to check Lenovo drivers from their website, You can adjust the brightness from power management too

Answer (score 1):

From Lenovo G580 [user guide](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/gseries_ug_en.pdf) page 27:

> <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd>: Increase/Decrease display
>   brightness

If this functionality is not available then you are missing needed drivers. You can get the latest drivers for your machine from [Lenovo technical support page](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/Lenovo-G-Series-laptops/Lenovo-G580-Notebook/downloads).